# Problem with Proteus Simulation of Buck Boost Converter - please help

Tags: simulation, solar-cell, proteus, buck-boost, panel

I built the attach circuit, I was simulating a solar panel buck boost voltage regulator to regulate the output voltage.
The problem is that while it works and shows the appropriate output. It doesnt't show the current, I attached probes in the circuit, but it shows I have little to none current passing thru the circuit.

It just seems like only voltage is passing thru the circuit and there is no current. 
Is there a way to also simulate a solar panel with a power rating?

P.S: I based the buck-boost circuit from here
http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/AN920-D.PDF
STEP UP/DOWN SWITCHINGREGULATOR OPERATION p. 18
enter image description here[image]

Comment: what is the short circuit output current of the solar panel in the simulation?

Comment: @jsotola the output current was very small, like 0.008A. Basically the same values you see in the picture above, but a much smaller voltage output.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have no current on the output is because you don't have a load that will draw any more.

As it stands, your load consists of R4, R5 and R7 in series. R7 is 100 Ohms, R5 is 12.9k and R4 is 1.5k. Add these together for 14.5k.

Now use Ohm's Law of V=I*R and re-arrange to solve for I - I = V/R. Plug in the numbers and you get I = 12.3/14500 = 0.000848276, which is pretty much what you have there.

Looks to me like your simulation is working properly.